# Cannot get AngularJS to work on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

I am trying to work with AngularJS on JSFiddle.

I've copied other similar projects to the T, but still, JSFiddle is giving me all sorts of errors when I try it in my own. Currently, it is telling me that is doesn't recognize my controller.

I'd really appreciate if someone could have a look at my really simple Fiddle and tell me why it is not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/ke10sq2v/

Here's the code:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller("Ctlr", ['$scope', function($Scope){
    $scope.hi = "yolo";
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="showBoxes=false">
  <div class="block" ng-show="showBoxes">Block 1</div>
  <div class="block" ng-show="showBoxes">Block 2</div>
  <button ng-click="showBoxes=!showBoxes">Toggle</button>
  <p>Show Boxes: {{showBoxes}} {{hi}}</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 15px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A few things:

You forgot to declare the `ngApp` directive in the HTML

You spelled `Ctrl` wrong in the controller defintion

You capitalized `$Scope` in the controller injection - but tried to reference `$scope`

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ke10sq2v/1/

IMPORTANT: (as per comment from Jack A. below)
You need to select one of the "No wrap" load types for the JavaScript. The default "on load" doesn't work with Angular...

Comment: Also, you need to select one of the "No wrap" load types for the JavaScript. The default "on load" doesn't work with Angular.